# How to scroll the gdb window within cgdb?

Tags: cgdb

While using cgdb, how does one scroll through the output visible in the gdb window?

Comment: Have you tried `alt+p/alt+n`, pageup/pagedown?

Comment: This is a good answer, not only does page up/page down scroll the cgdb windows, but alt + up arrow, alt + down arrow will scroll the source window.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

PgUp and PgDn should scroll the gdb window.  If they don't, check your `TERM` environment variable and make sure it's set correctly.

Comment: For anyone wondering, `i` should do the trick when you want to exit scroll mode.

Comment: Is it possible to scroll up by one line ?