# To scroll in gdb window using Termdebug in Vim

Tags: vim, gdb

I'm using vim since a while to code in c++, and I use the plugin Termdebug to have the gdb window included in vim, with all the commands easily usable etc... my problem is that I can't scroll up or down in the gdb command window and in the output window, because up and down arrows only show precedent and next commands, none of the combo I tried worked (like C-Up or A-Up). I already tried some solutions:

- **lauching vim with :let g:termdebug_use_prompt = 1**, so I can go in normal mode in the termdebug windows. It worked, but the text displayed is ugly and buggy (text which was bold isn't anymore, random line breaks in the middle of lines...).
- <s>**as [How to scroll the gdb window within cgdb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12682821/how-to-scroll-the-gdb-window-within-cgdb) says, using PageUp/PageDown**, but my laptop doesn't have these keys. I tried to map new combinations of keys with https://github.com/sezanzeb/key-mapper or by modifying ~/.config/openbox/lxqt-rc.xml, but when I tried them it only wrote "3~" and ";3~" whether in Vim or in Qterminal btw.</s>  Edit : tried with another computer with Page Up / Down key, doesn't work.
- <del>**Using C-w + :C-y**, as C-w make it possible to enter vim commands in the gdb window and C-y scroll up in vim. In the vim and the gdb window, it raises an E464 Error, saying the command is ambiguous.</del>  Edit : vim commands doesn't seem to work at all in gdb windows, command :go which should move the cursor to the beginning of the file has no effect.

If someone has a solution making it possible to switch between modes in the gdb window, but with a correct display it would be perfect, allowing me to use all my vim maps in the gdb window, however just a solution to scroll would already save me.

Comment: Revert your question to its pristine state and post an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Problem solved ! Doing "C-W N" in the gdb and/or in the I/O window switch them to normal mode, making possible the scrolling.